# facebook graph API stopped working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I generated my access token as I was doing everyday. Two days before, I used the event ID to get the details of this event:

```
1852415531478014
```

the facebook event is this

https://www.facebook.com/events/1852415531478014/

But today, the graph API returns this error

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1852415531478014' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100,
  "error_subcode": 33,
  "fbtrace_id": "BxdCziS18mQ"
  }
}
```

This was working perfectly fine till day before yesterday and has now stopped working. I am using the same user access token in the explorer tool

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

I have a facebook app and I am using the App token in the explorer to get details of the event using the event ID

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review (Thanks to Cambridge Analytica!)

Comment: so how do i get my app reviewed? Do i have to do anything to get it reviewed of will facebook review it automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think they stopped reviewing Apps till further notice.
Access your  App dashboard through developer.facebook.com and find out more.